# How to narrow this question (or where to move it)?

Tags: discussion

I have a question here that was marked as too broad: [Determining who owns a transferrable item in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548194/determing-who-owns-a-transferrable-item-mysql)

I always try to write good questions but obviously I have failed here and I want to know how I can do better, both now and in the future.

At first I thought the question was fairly specific since I even provided example tables; however, I can see that the questions in my last paragraph are broad and open to subjective responses.

I am thinking a good start would be to replace the last paragraph with: "How can I normalize this table structure without sacrificing performance?" Does that improve the question, or am I just putting new paint on a broken car?

Would the question go better on another SE? (database admins?)

Comment: *"How can I normalize this table structure without sacrificing performance?"* that still seems a bit... broad to me. The first comment on your question summarizes why.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; do you have any suggestion for how to narrow it, or does that seem impossible?

Comment: I'd start by removing either the normalization request or the performance requirement. The two interacting together makes any answer to the question have to cover far more information to be complete.

Comment: Hmm.. I was looking at it from the opposite angle. The domain of solutions that only normalize the tables is larger than the domain of solutions that normalize the tables without sacrificing performance, so I thought including both aspects made it a more *narrow* question.

Comment: Maybe it's just my lack of domain knowledge. When i think of database normalization, there's usually only one answer, the fully normalized database structure. you can make sacrifices here and there, sacrificing full normalization for performance improvements, but that's going to depend on the content and usage of your database/tables.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong in thinking there is more than one way to normalize this particular problem. I'll rethink from that perspective.

Answer (score 4):

To address the "or where to move it?" aspect of your question:

If a question is too broad on one site then there's a very good chance it would be too broad on another.

More or less the same rules for a question's focus apply on Programmers, or DBA.SE as they do on Stack Overflow.

The guidance is that if it would take a book to answer the question then it's too broad. What Stack Exchange is looking for is relatively short but detailed answers. Yes, some answers are long, but that's usually the detail that drives that.

I don't consider myself a database expert, so I can't really comment on how you can focus your question, other than to say perhaps to look at a more specific question rather than the general "how can I do X?" you have asked.

Comment: Programmers specifically takes a broader scope of question than SO, but I don't know if database design belongs there. Would you mind giving some advice on *how* to narrow the question?

Comment: @user45623 - I can say fairly authoritatively that Programmers *doesn't* take questions that are significantly broader than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user45623 - I was also specifically answering the "move it somewhere else" aspect of your question.

Comment: Programmers takes *conceptual* questions, which I think of as "broader" than SO but that may just be my opinion. Thanks for tweaking the answer, I understand where you are coming from better now.

Comment: @user45623 yes, Programmers take conceptual questions, but they still have to be focused. *(BTW, I am also a mod on Programmers)*

Comment: @user45623 consider giving a read to **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**